How to cast forwarded arguments to std::invoke conditionally (if it's a certain class) which came from std::forward'ed template (SFINAE?)?
I have created a class member invocation function, which does a delayed call, like:
func = NotifyAll(
    &get_file_listener,
    &GetFileListener::OnGetFileSuccess, container.c_str(), name.c_str());
// ... long delay and different scope
func();

But due to the nature of "execution occurring later" I realize that variables are captured by value will work, but obviously this won't work for char* arguments, as in:
class ListenerInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ListenerInterface() {}
};

class GetFileListener: public ListenerInterface {
public:
    virtual void OnGetFileSuccess(const char* container, const char* name);
    virtual ~GetFileListener();
};

I have done this by templating and forwarding the member function and class type, then calling the function when required (creating the notification with NotifyAll, and by calling the returning lambda it calls NotifyAllNow):
template<typename> struct extract_class_from_member_function_ptr;

template <typename RET_T, typename CLASS, class... ArgTypes>
struct extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<RET_T(CLASS::*)(ArgTypes...)> {
    using type = CLASS;
};

template <typename RET_T, typename CLASS, class... ArgTypes>
struct extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<RET_T(CLASS::* const)(ArgTypes...)> {
    using type = CLASS;
};

template <typename RET_T, typename CLASS, class... ArgTypes>
struct extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<RET_T(CLASS::*&)(ArgTypes...)> {
    using type = CLASS;
};

template <typename RET_T, typename CLASS, class... ArgTypes>
struct extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<RET_T(CLASS::* const&)(ArgTypes...)> {
    using type = CLASS;
};

template <typename T, class FuncT, class... ArgTypes>
void NotifyAllNow(T* one_time_specific_listener, FuncT&& Function, ArgTypes&&... Arguments) {
    using BaseT = extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<FuncT>::type;

    BaseT* casted_listener = (BaseT*)(one_time_specific_listener);
    //assert(casted_listener != nullptr);

    std::invoke(std::forward<FuncT>(Function), casted_listener, std::forward<ArgTypes>(Arguments)...);
}

template <typename... ArgTypes>
auto NotifyAll(ArgTypes&&... Arguments)
{
     return std::bind_front([](auto&&... args) {
        NotifyAllNow(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        }, std::forward<ArgTypes>(Arguments)...);
}

I somehow need to extend the life of some parameters, I think something like an optional LifeExtender (or something else) could work:

class LifeExtender {
    std::optional<std::string> data;
public:
    LifeExtender(const char* const str) : data{} {
        if (str != nullptr) {
            data = std::string(str);
        }
    }

    LifeExtender(char* str) : data{} {
        if (str != nullptr) {
            data = std::string(str);
        }
    }

    LifeExtender(const std::string& str) : data{str} {}

    ~LifeExtender() {}

    operator const char* const() const noexcept {
        if (data) {
            return data->c_str();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    operator char*() const noexcept {
        if (data) {
            return (char*)data->c_str();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
};

So that I could just do:
func_fixed = NotifyAll(
    get_file_listener,
    &GetFileListener::OnGetFileSuccess, LifeExtender(container), LifeExtender(name));

And have everything work.
But now I'm stuck with trying to cast any LifeExtender object to char* 's (in this case by just calling the char* typecast on them) in the templated invoke:
std::invoke(std::forward<FuncT>(Function), casted_listener, std::forward<ArgTypes>(Arguments)...);

I have no idea how to "for each forwarded argument" perform an std::conditional_t or make a separate specialization using std::enable_if to cast to char* when the argument is of type LifeExtender, and just pass it along if not.
I think I should be taking inspiration form this post: Using std::forward on casted arguments
But templates are still difficult for me sometimes, I don't think I know how to apply this.
What would be the correct way to solve this life extension issue in some neat way, so that it would allow me to keep calling member functions later (issue notifications)?
I unfortunately cannot change the parameters of the methods which receive the notifications as they are not controlled by me at all, I have to pass char*'s unfortunately.
Changing everything to std::string would make this a non-issue, but I have to work with the cards I was dealt.
A full example can be found here:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfd98a9e6cad0f43
--------------------------
Edit: I tried creating identity/forwarding functions (I think I didn't do it correctly):
class LifeExtender;
template< typename V>
inline typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<V, LifeExtender>::value, V&&>::type identity(V&& v)
{
    return std::forward<V>(v);
}

template< typename V>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<V, LifeExtender>::value, char*&&>::type identity(V&& v)
{
    return std::forward<char*>(v);
}

template <typename T, class FuncT, class... ArgTypes>
void NotifyAllNow(T* one_time_specific_listener, FuncT&& Function, ArgTypes&&... Arguments) {
    using BaseT = extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<FuncT>::type;

    BaseT* casted_listener = (BaseT*)(one_time_specific_listener);
    //assert(casted_listener != nullptr);

    std::invoke(std::forward<FuncT>(Function), casted_listener, identity(Arguments)...);
}

But still compilation errors occur when doing:
// VVVVV ERROR VVVVV
        //func_fixed = NotifyAll(
        //  get_file_listener,
        //  &GetFileListener::OnGetFileSuccess, LifeExtender(container), LifeExtender(name)); 
// ^^^^^ ERROR ^^^^^
// 'void NotifyAllNow(T *,FuncT &&,ArgTypes &&...)': could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from 'GetFileListener'

        get_file_listener.OnGetFileSuccess(identity(LifeExtender(container)), identity(LifeExtender(name))); // fine
        get_file_listener.OnGetFileSuccess(LifeExtender(container), LifeExtender(name)); // fine
        func = NotifyAll(
            &get_file_listener,
            &GetFileListener::OnGetFileSuccess, container.c_str(), name.c_str());
    }

    func(); // referencing deallocated memory 'container' and 'name' here
    //func_fixed(); // works as expected without UB

--------------------------
Edit2:
For now I have solved this problem as this: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d78414211a49624
But it does not feel like the correct solution. I think too many copies are being made (I'm fine with using this as-is, but I would love to have "the correct" solution).
I have for now removed the && from NotifyAll, and added the life extender function usage, and tried to optimize this a bit more with a move:
template<typename T>
inline T&& extend(typename std::enable_if<
    !std::same_as<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, const char*> && 
    !std::same_as<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, char*>, T&&>::type v)
{
    return std::forward<T>(std::move(v));
}

template<typename T>
inline char*&& extend(char*&& v)
{
    // Hey there, 
    // if you're debugging this code, and passing char* 's to a notification, 
    // make sure there will be no lifetime/scope issues!
    // Here I'm just forwarding the char* ptr..
    // If you want to use automatic life extension then consider casting it to const char*.
    return std::forward<char*>(std::move(v));
}

template<typename T>
inline LifeExtender extend(const char*&& v)
{
    return std::forward<LifeExtender>(std::move(LifeExtender(v)));
}

template <typename... ArgTypes>
auto NotifyAll(ArgTypes... Arguments) // unfortunately I don't know how to make this more efficient by using ArgTypes&&, it causes so much lvalue <=> rvalue errors/headaches
{
    return std::bind_front([](auto&&... args) {
        NotifyAllNow(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        }, extend<decltype(Arguments)>(std::move(Arguments))...);
}

For the invoke I use the 'identity' functions (don't know if that's the correct name here, I think it's wrong but I need to go with something):
template<typename V>
inline typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<V, LifeExtender>::value, V&&>::type identity(V&& v)
{
    return std::forward<V>(v);
}

template<typename V>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<V, LifeExtender>::value, char*&&>::type identity(V&& v)
{
    return std::forward<char*>(v);
}

template <typename T, class FuncT, class... ArgTypes>
void NotifyAllNow(T* one_time_specific_listener, FuncT&& Function, ArgTypes&&... Arguments) {
    using BaseT = extract_class_from_member_function_ptr<FuncT>::type;

    BaseT* casted_listener = (BaseT*)(one_time_specific_listener);
    //assert(casted_listener != nullptr);

    std::invoke(std::forward<FuncT>(Function), casted_listener, identity(Arguments)...);
}

Using it like this works fine:
class ListenerInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ListenerInterface() {}
};

struct extra {
    int i;
};

class GetFileListener : public ListenerInterface {
public:
    virtual void OnGetFileSuccess(const char* container, const char* name, extra* other, int i, float f, double d, char c, const extra& x, extra x2, const extra& x3, extra x4) {
        std::cout << "container_ptr: " << (void*)container << "\n" << "name_ptr: " << (void*)name << "\n" << "container: " << container << "\n" << "name: " << name << "\n";
    }
    virtual ~GetFileListener() {}
};

std::function<void(void)> issue_indirect_notification(const char* container, const char* name, GetFileListener* listener) {
    extra xx{ 99 };
    float f = 0.0f;
    double d = 0.0;
    char c = 'a';

    NotifyAll(
        listener,
        &GetFileListener::OnGetFileSuccess, container, name, &xx, xx.i, f, d, c, extra{ 42 }, extra{ 42 }, extra{ 42 }, extra{ 42 });

    return NotifyAll(
        listener,
        &GetFileListener::OnGetFileSuccess, container, name, &xx, 120, 120.0f, 120.0, 'a', xx, xx, xx, xx);
}

int main() {
    GetFileListener get_file_listener{};
    std::function<void(void)> func;
    {
        std::string container{ "" };
        std::string name{ "" };

        int q = 10 + rand() % 256;
        int w = 10 + rand() % 256;

        for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i) { container.push_back((char)('A' + rand() % 26)); }
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) { name.push_back((char)('A' + rand() % 26)); }

        func = issue_indirect_notification(container.c_str(), name.c_str(), &get_file_listener);
    }

    func(); // referencing 'container' and 'name' here (above code extends the life of these)

    return 0;
}

But as soon as I try optimize the NotifyAll function with references or moves, unfortunately the above code breaks, which is to be expected from one side, but from another side of the story, this code "worked" fine (except it didn't keep pointed to memory alive) with all kinds of different parameters:
template <typename... ArgTypes>
auto NotifyAll(ArgTypes&&... Arguments)
{
    return std::bind_front([this](auto&&... args) {
        NotifyAllNow(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        }, std::forward<ArgTypes>(Arguments)...);
}

I know I'm not that great at template programming, but I am trying to improve.

I dont understand what () you want to call. Your LifeExtender has operator const char* which is non-explicit, ie should be taken into account for implicit conversions (and it has no operator())

for the specific question you can write an identity function that does nothing but forward its parameter, but has a specialization for Lifeextender

@463035818_is_not_an_ai you are right, I forgot this is an overloaded typecast. I wanted to (ab)use SFINAE to make the std::invoke "just work", but unfortunately it results in errors for parameters that expect a const char* and instead get a LifeExtender, even when I add an cast overload for operator char*() const noexcept (although this should not be needed in my case, SFINAE I would expect to just work).

Can you give an example of what you mean? I'll try to look up identity functions and see if I can come up with anything myself. Thanks!

"but obviously this won't work for char* arguments" -- This is neither obvious nor true. There is nothing special about the type char* with regard to this. What doesn't work is having to transform a parameter via a (member) function call, where the lifetime of the result is tied to the lifetime of the original parameter.

@JaMiT I should have worded that better, in this context the resulting actions access possibly freed memory, which is UB, due to the char* not being an object that can manage the lifetime of the pointed to memory. Sorry for the bad wording. Your comment is right.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai it's working now, late night debugging caused me to not spot the missing addressof & operator in my modified example

You are just complicating a simple problem. Just try boost.signals2. Read the doc, and don't reinvent the wheel. The hardest case can be solved through cautious use of shared_ptr. Read more than you write.

@Red.Wave If that's the case, how would you, when the interface is set in stone, tell old applications/callers to wrap the char* in a shared_ptr for me? A copy will always be needed, and a shared_ptr is overkill, std::string is fine, unique_ptr would suffice, but a copy of the data is still needed. As far as I see boost signals also won't solve the problem of providing arguments/values "now" and calling the signal in another scope /a "later" time. I don't see that anywhere in the docs, so it would still require me to use something NotifyAll-alike which in the body uses boost signals..

The interface of boost.signals2 is very convenient. you can track some objects. But if you want to store a copy, then either use a lambda capturing a copy, or std::bind the copy. It's that simple. Creating tracking and holding the copy is the slot's responsibility. A signal is just supposed to shoot all its slots on invocation.
